# resultset encoding problems

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, resultset, jena

My resultset contains special characters and umlauts. I tried different solutions and the first one which prints out the text without encoding problems is this one:

```
List<QuerySolution> list = ResultSetFormatter.toList(myResultSet);  
for (QuerySolution querySolution : list) {
    System.out.println(querySolution);   }
```

Instead of this I prefer a direct output like:

```
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, myResultSet, myQuery);
```

But when I use this, there's my encoding problem again.
I'm using jena library in java.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Is the encoding problem the same in the Windows command line and in your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your terminal is using a non-UTF-8 encoding.

The various `ResultSetFormatter.out` methods take an `OutputStream` rather than a `Writer`, that is they will output bytes rather than characters. As a consequence it needs to pick an encoding, and UTF-8 is the obvious choice.

You might reasonable wonder what the deal is with `System.out`. It's a bit archaic, a hybrid `OutputStream` but with some methods that accept strings that it will encode using the platform default encoding.

Thus the first method works -- `System.out.println(querySolution)` uses the default platform encoding that matches your terminal -- whereas the second will use UTF-8.

[`ResultSetFormatter`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSetFormatter.html) has no methods which accept a `Writer` (an omission), so I'd suggest either using:

```
System.out.println(ResultSetFormatter.asText(myResultSet, myQuery));
```

which will be fine for small result sets, or:

```
TextOutput fmt = new TextOutput(myQuery);
fmt.format(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, Charset.defaultCharset()), myResultSet);
```

which will stream, and should use the same encoding as `System.out.println()`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I played with System.out and several outputstreams but you can't modify the char set. thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: Beware about using non-UTF-8 encoding.  There may be characters that can't be written.  As RDF data is sometimes in a mixture of languages and hence scripts, characters from different places may occur in one result set.  UTF-8 can handle that.

Comment: Good point. I'd suggest trying to get your terminal into utf-8 mode which might make your life more pleasant.